# Bootstrap no funciona bien con Split.js

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, vue.js, split

Estoy trabajando con Split.js y Bootstrap y he observado que Bootstrap "solo hace caso del tamaño de la ventana" para el funcionamiento del grid. En otras palabras, que no funciona bien cuando se redimensionan los divs con Split.js.

Aquí me asalta la duda de si hay algún modo de que Bootstrap reaccione en función del  en el que se coloca el código en lugar de en función de la ventana.

He hecho una demo que os dejo [AQUÍ](https://jsfiddle.net/Bucle/kLfus6pe/5/), en ella vais a poder ver lo que os digo. Lo curioso es que jsfiddle también tiene "Splits" y con estos si que funciona, aunque parece que ellos no usan Split.js, pero no he podido ver como lo hacen ellos. El caso es que cambiar Split.js por otra librería es una locura a estas alturas y sería mi última opción. Tampoco he encontrado ningún tema relacionado por internet.

```html
<div id="a" class="split content blue">
  <row>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-8 yellow">
      asdasd
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-sm-7 col-xs-4 orange">
      asdasd
    </div>
  </row>
</div>
<div id="b" class="split">
    <div id="d" class="split content split-horizontal red">
      <row>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-8 yellow">
          asdasd
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-sm-7 col-xs-4 orange">
          asdasd
        </div>
      </row>
    </div>
    <div id="e" class="split content split-horizontal"></div>
    <div id="f" class="split content split-horizontal"></div>
</div>
<div id="c" class="split content">
</div>
```

```js
Split(['#a', '#b', '#c'], {
  gutterSize: 20,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  direction: 'vertical',
});
Split(['#d', '#e', '#f'], {
  sizes: [15, 70, 15],
  gutterSize: 20,
  cursor: 'row-resize',
});
```

```css
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/split.js/1.3.5/split.min.js"></script>
<style>

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.split {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #e4e4e4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.gutter {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
}

.gutter.gutter-horizontal {
  cursor: col-resize;
  background-image: url('../grips/vertical.png');
}

.gutter.gutter-vertical {
  cursor: row-resize;
  background-image: url('../grips/horizontal.png');
}

.split.split-horizontal,
.gutter.gutter-horizontal {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código en ella para mejor visibilidad.

Comment: Gracias @gugadev, ya lo he añadido.